# Ubuntu nginx 404 error

Tags: ubuntu, web

[cryptopals site](http://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/1/python)

Can you access this webpage? It says to me

404 Not Found

nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

I am using Ubuntu 14.1, newest version. I searched on Google but didn't find anything that could help me solve this problem.. 
I don't know if it is a problem related to the website or my computer..

Comment: 404 Page is removed or Moved, the webmaster usually fix theese error, report to the admin of that website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a server side error, you can do nothing else than contact webmaster to notify that a page that previously was here is not anymore.

This is a very classical error, and often it is never fixed since the page was just removed due to reowrk or because its content is not anymore considered like accurate.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes